# JavaScriptに最も適したエディターを探しています

Tags: javascript, windows

JavaScriptのコードを作成したり編集するためのエディターを探しています。
お勧めのものを教えてください。

※日本語対応のものでお願い致します。

作業環境：Windows7Pro

【質問の背景】
私はWeb系の開発を始めたばかりなのですが、今のところWindows標準のメモ帳でJavaScriptやHTMLのファイルを開いてソースコードの内容を確認しています。
しかしながら、JavaScriptのコードを扱うに当り、HTMLの中に埋め込まれているものを探し出してXXXXXXXX.jsファイルを開いてコードの追加・編集・削除を行うことに手間がかかっています。
そこで、作業の迅速化を図るためにJavaScriptを扱うための比較的良くコードの編集に適したものを、経験者のご意見を参考にして作業を快適に進めていきたいと考えたので、今回の質問に至りました。

Comment: [「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/x%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80%e8%a6%a7%e3%81%8c%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e5%82%be%e5%90%91%e3%81%a8%e4%bb%96%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c/1382#1382)を読まれてから、質問文の扱うテーマをもう少し絞るなどをお勧めします。例えば、現在は何を使っていて、どういう点を改善したいか等

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
ちょっと今、時間が無いので後ほど読んでから、なるべくガイドラインにそった記述方法で質問を訂正します。

Comment: FYI: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130114/ http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58824/

Comment: やっとスタックオーバーフローのサイトに訪問する時間が取れたのでで、今回の質問に追記してみました。ただ、追記した内容もガイドラインに合っているのかもよく分かりませ‌​ん・・・

Answer (score 4):

もし**エディタの操作に慣れるまで時間をかける余裕がある**のでしたら、私もuser2617876さんと同様Vimをおすすめします。Windowsかつ日本語環境とのことなので、[Vim — KaoriYa](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/) からダウンロードして使ってみるといいと思います。

質問文に

> JavaScriptのコードを扱うに当り、HTMLの中に埋め込まれているものを探し出してXXXXXXXX.jsファイルを開いてコードの追加・編集・削除を行うことに手間がかかっています

とありますが、Vimの場合、ファイルが相対パスで指定されていれば、ファイル名の上にカーソルを持って行って`gf`とタイプするだけで目的のファイルが開けます。

また、Web系の開発をされていると、後々Unix系のサーバーにSSH接続してファイルを操作する、という事も必要になるかと思います。Vimはそのようなサーバーでもたいてい利用できますし、場合によってはVimで操作するしかないこともあるかもしれません。なので、とりあえずVimの操作に慣れておくのは損にはならないのではないかな、と思ってお薦めさせていただきました。

Comment: vimが良いのですね。
私は15年前UNIXをガンガン使っていました。
もちろんviも。
でも、15年も経てばさすがにviのコマンドもほとんど覚えていません。
viを思い出すのに丁度良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

簡単なものであれば[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)を使っています。

多くのプログラミング言語に対応しているので、
新しい言語に触れてみようとするときに向いています。

軽量でそれほど学習コストもかかりませんが、
機能もそれなりです。

本格的な開発をされるなら、
他の方が紹介しているエディターに乗り換えるべきだと思います。

Comment: Web系超初心者にとってNotepad++が合っているかもしれませんね。
使ってみて、取り急ぎNotepad++が現時点の私の実力で十分な機能が備わっているのであれば、このエディタが一番良さそうな気がします。

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)にJavaScript系のプラグインをインストールして使用するという方法もありかなと思います。

http://tomoyamkung.net/2014/03/11/sublimetext3-setting-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

"テキストエディタでjsファイルを編集する"のであれば
[サクラエディタ](http://sakura-editor.sourceforge.net/index.html)が良いかと思います。
理由としては
・言語ごとの設定が可能(拡張子関連付け・一時適応など)
・言語ごとにカラー強調などの設定が可能
・拡張で入力保管やキーワードヘルプ機能を使用できる。
以上のような機能が便利です。
自分はPHPなども触るのですが簡単な編集程度であれば此方を使用しています。

有料・無料の指定が無かったので無料のテキストエディタをあげましたが、
有料ですが開発するのであればVisualStudioが便利ですね……。
Web開発でも「visual studio web developer」とかありますし……。

Answer (score 0):

自分の周辺にいるJavaScriptをメインに書いてるエンジニアはWebStormを使ってる人が多いです。
JavaScriptも書くし、他の動的型付け言語も書いてる人の場合はVimとかEmacsを使う人が多い印象です。

AtomというエディタだとプラグインもJavaScriptで書けるので、エディタもJavaScriptにしたいっていう修行を行いたい場合はAtomでも良いと思います。

Comment: WebStormですね。
有償のエディタのようですが、それだけ素敵な機能が装備されているのでしょうね。
もし有用であれば購入を検討しています。

Answer (score 0):

個人的な好みですが
SublimeText
が好きですね。

Grunt等も叩けるので...

Answer (score -2):

[Vim](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/)がおすすめです。スーパーハカーの気分になれます。

Comment: Vimですか！
Vimが説明されているサイトを見てみましたが、少々クセのあるエディタのようですね。
でも、お勧めであれば、とりあえず使ってみようと思います。